# Convert List by Source to List by drawing order using arcpy

Tags: arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, arcpy

When I do some calculations, it results in adding a table to TOC which converts "List by drawing order" to "List by Source". I want to convert it back to "List by drawing order" using arcpy and I am not able to find anything relevant to it in help files. Any suggestion?

Comment: I looked for a Table of Contents Option to stop this behaviour when using ArcMap through the GUI and there is none that I could find.  I think there needs to be an ArcGIS Idea located/created to allow both the GUI and ArcPy control whether adding tables triggers the List By Source View of the TOC to be used.

Comment: ArcGIS [Idea](https://c.na9.visual.force.com/apex/ideaView?id=087E00000004hFK&returnUrl=%2Fapex%2FideaList%3Fc%3D09a300000004xET%26sort%3Drecent) created. Please promote it. Thanks!